Setting press time for DragGestureRecognizer in .Net Maui
Is there a way to change the default press time for the drag gesture to be recognized?
Thanks
Marcos
I haven't found anything besides writing a custom recognizer from scratch or somehow use TouchBehavior. I am looking for something simpler if possible.

The drag gesture is recognized by a long press, and a timer can be defined in the DragStarting method to get the current drag position within the time that the timer is executed, and then compare.For more information,please refer to DragGesture.

2.Can you tell me the platform you are using ?
